# Regex for parsing mentioned usernames from Instagram captions

Tags: regex

I've been trying to create a Regex to parse mentioned usernames from Instagram captions.

`@men.tion._`, `@men.tion._`, `@men.tion._.`, `(@men.tion._)`, and `(@men.tion._.)` should all return `men.tion._`. Feel free to correct me if this is incorrect — I haven't been able to find any information on how Instagram parses the usernames itself.

So far, I've come up with `(?<=(^|\W)@)(?<username>[\w\._]+)(?=(\.|\W))`, but it doesn't quite work.

Comment: side note: dots, and most other special-meaning characters, do not need escaping within character classes. ie `[\w\._]` is the same as `[\w._]`.

Comment: More, `[\w._]` = `[\w.]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\B@(?<username>\w+(?:\.\w+)*)
```

**Details**

- `\B@` - a `@` that is either at the start of string or a non-word char
- `(?<username>\w+(?:\.\w+)*)` - Group "username":

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\.\w+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `.` and 1+ word chars.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugQ5yY/2).